Best practice to set string labels to vertices in Geometry Nodes?
I want to set string labels to vertices in Geometry Nodes.
I also want to load these strings with Python from a CSV file.
Here's an approach using a "Repeat Zone" together with the "Index Switch" node.
It's working, but not very pretty.
Any ideas if the same is also possible to achieve without using a repeat zone?
Suggestions are very welcome!



Is your question about a better way to set string labels on vertices in Geometry Nodes, or a cleaner way to look up strings from an array by index number? [They might be the same, but I just want the question to be clear.]
